# How can I share constructor code with readonly class members?

Tags: c#, constructor, dry

I have a class, `FooBarSet` with a single "core" chunk of initialization logic.

A `FooBar` is made of a `Foo` and a `Bar`.  Class `FooBarSet` is initialized with a list of `FooBar`.  `FooBarSet` can *also* be initialized by separate parallel `Foo` and `Bar` lists.

Ideally, I could run it like this:

```
public class FooBarSet
{
    private readonly List<FooBar> _list;

    // Primary constructor.
    public FooBarSet(List<FooBar> foobarList)
    {
        // Contracts and initialization...
        _list = foobarList;
    }

    // Secondary constructor.
    public FooBarSet(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) 
    {
        // Zip a new list of new FooBars
        var zipped = fooList.Zip(barList,
                                 (foo, bar) => new FooBar(foo, bar));

        // Call primary constructor with zipped list.
        this(zipped);
    }
}
```

This is C#, not Java, so `this(zipped)` is illegal.  The common solution, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123026/3367144), is to pull the core initialization into a common private method:

```
public class FooBarSet
{
    private readonly List<FooBar> _list;

    // Common "constructor" called from actual constructors.
    private Init(List<FooBar> foobarList)
    {
        // Contracts and initialization...
        _list = foobarList;
    }

    public FooBarSet(List<FooBar> foobarList)
    {
        Init(foobarList);
    }

    public FooBarSet(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) 
    {
        var zipped = fooList.Zip(barList,
                                 (foo, bar) => new FooBar(foo, bar));

        Init(zipped);
    }

}
```

However, this doesn't work either, because of the `readonly _list` field.

**Assuming that `_list` must be `readonly`, how can I get these constructors to share initialization code?**

Comment: `_list = Init(foobarList)` in the constructor? Make `Init` return the `List<FooBar>` instead.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I like that a lot.  It'll work for my actual implementation, not just the [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) I used.  Throw it down as an answer and it's yours as long as something crazy beautiful doesn't pop up.

Comment: Side note: only the _reference_ to the list is readonly, you can change the **contents** whenever you want.  The obvious solution, then....

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, I'm assuming you imply removing the `readonly` modifier.  In this [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example), that is certainly the way to do it :-)  But in my actual use case, that reference is to an immutable reference type.

Comment: No, the idea was that you could just change the contents, but leave the reference still `readonly`.  Obviously, this won't work if the actual type is immutable (which was left out of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to get the `Init` method return the value to be set in the constructor:

```
public class FooBarSet
{
    private readonly List<FooBar> _list;

    // Common "constructor" called from actual constructors.
    private List<FooBar> Init(List<FooBar> foobarList)
    {
        // Contracts and initialization...
        return whateverList;
    }

    public FooBarSet(List<FooBar> foobarList)
    {
        _list = Init(foobarList);
    }

    public FooBarSet(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) 
    {
        var zipped = fooList.Zip(barList,
                                 (foo, bar) => new FooBar(foo, bar));

        _list = Init(zipped);
    }

}
```

Comment: And the extension to this, if you happen to have multiple `readonly` members, is to have an `Init()` method for each of them.  (Hopefully the number of `readonly` members isn't large or growing.)

Answer (score 3):

You can move the "zipper" code to a static function and use that:

```
public class FooBarSet
{
    private readonly List<FooBar> _list;

    private static List<FooBar> Prepare( List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList )
    {
        return fooList.Zip(barList, (foo, bar) => new FooBar(foo, bar));
    }

    public FooBarSet(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) :
        this( Prepare( fooList, barList ) )
    {
    }

    public FooBarSet(List<FooBar> zippedList)
    {
        _list = zippedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think every time I've ever used the "base" constructor syntax, `: this( StaticMethod( bla, bloo)` or  `: base( OtherStatic( bloo, blee)`, the constructor using it has been completely empty.  Is this always the case?

Comment: @kdbanman no, you can chain constructors pretty deep like that by calling other constructors with default values and keeping the initialization in one constructor.

Comment: @RonBeyer, sorry, I don't think that's what I meant.  Notice how the body of the two-parameter constructor is empty?  Whenever I set up an alternative constructor like that (using the `: this()` syntax), it's body always ends up empty.  Hence, for each one of those empty constructors, I end up with a static method that contains the code I *would've* put in a Java-style alternative constructor.